# Run command in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am calling php from node.js like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var result = exec('php index.php decrypt decrypt1 ' + s1, function(error, stdout, stderr) {

 });
```

You can see this is using child process. But I don't want to use child process. Because it is working asynchronous. How can I run linux command in node.js without using child process?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ShellJS - Unix shell commands for Node.js](http://documentup.com/arturadib/shelljs). It has both sync and async calls. Here's an example:

```
require('shelljs/global');
exec('php -v').output;
```

and when you run this file, here's what you get:

```
PHP 5.5.24 (cli) (built: May 19 2015 10:10:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use child_process.execSync if you want to run your script synchronously.